# Using SQL developer to automate several sql scripts

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have several scripts that I run in SQL Developer every day. I have it set up as @script_1.sql; @script_2.sql; @script_n.sql; and I hit F5 and let it run through all my scripts and then look at my results when it has finished parsing through all of them. I want to have this automated so it is finished running those scripts by the time I get into work. My system admins have disabled task scheduler. I have a few jobs set up that work fine but when I tried turning this into a job it wouldn't work. How would I automate this using only SQL Developer?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a package and convert those SQL files into its procedures. Then schedule their execution with `DBMS_JOB` or `DBMS_SCHEDULER` package.